# How to display the motion path of bones in pose mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, workflow, visibility

I'm making animation with a single bone for UE4. The motion path is showing when I animate an object in *Object Mode* but not in pose mode. Is there any way to display the motion path of a bone in *Pose Mode*?

Comment: You have to enable the motion path under the armature properties (green pictogram), not the object properties (orange square).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**Use the Calculate available in Pose Menu.**

[image]

With a pose bone or bones selected in pose mode, go to *`Pose > Motion Paths > Calculate`*

Or as mentioned by [@FFeller](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214560/how-to-display-the-motion-path-of-bones-in-pose-mode/214787#comment362125_214560) in the Armature (DATA) Motion Paths panel.

[image]

Comment: Still not wednesday 7am.